# how to return a promise between actions in vuejs/vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, action

I have a main action (ActionA) in Vuex that makes the treatment of the variable 'output'.

However, i need to execute another action (ActionB) in the middle and then it continues to execute in (ActionA) with the modifications that (ActionB) made on 'output'

```
async ActionA({commit, dispatch}, input){
    let output
    [BLOCK A1]

    await dispatch('ActionB', output)
    
    [BLOCK A2]
    commit('MutationA', { output })
},

async ActionB(?, output){
    
       output
       [BLOCK B] 
        
},
```

Is there anyway to send it back the variable 'output' to (ActionA) with all modifications that was made by (ActionB)?

Comment: You can access the state again in the second action: https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#actions

Comment: I dont get it. The 'output' is a local variable. Do I need to convert to a global variable inside an action?

Comment: Set it as a Vuex state, define it in an upper scope (than Vuex) or get it as a return from another action.

Comment: ActionB could: **a)** commit to state as @kissu suggested, so you could read from state after awaiting ActionB's dispatch, or **b)** return the desired `result`. So in ActionA you could do `const result = await.dispatch('ActionB', output); // use result`. Note vuex actions are automatically wrapped in promises. So a simple `return result` is the equivalent of a `return Promise.resolve(result)` in a regular function.